# Having trouble finding lighting normals per pixel rather than per fragment

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working on a game with fairly low-polygon models, so when I try to implement directional lighting, I end up getting unsightly edges like the per-face example in [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/13wi/projects/modeler/normals.png) picture (not my picture) where the
model's mesh is clearly visible.

I have tried many tutorials for fragment lighting in the hopes that I can smooth it out, but I can't figure out how they calculate a normal for each fragment. I just want to know how to calculate a normal for each pixel -- I know how to take care of all the other aspects of lighting I need.

Comment: Calculate a normal for each vertex and interpolate it over the face.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? My current setup doesn't easily allow for anything other than per-face normals

Comment: That title is rather odd. The only difference between per-pixel and per-fragment is that pixels are what become of fragments after blending. You blend the source fragment (fragment shader output) with the destination pixel (color buffer) and the result is a pixel. Unless you're dealing with something like deferred shading, you won't even have a per-pixel normal (because the normal is not needed after or even output by the fragment shader).

Comment: @ddkerado: No, there is no other solution. When using per-face normals the color will always be constant over a face.